# server to client message using async in signalr

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

currently i'm using this code to send to each client a slightly different message. When there are 100+ clients, this same code without task is blocking my timer loop, and i suspect it to also block all web requests.

```
ConcurrentDictionary Sessions;
// ...


var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TiHub>();
foreach(var kp in Sessions) 
{
    var client = context.Clients.Client(kp.Key);
    if (client != null)
     {
          client.changed(new Data{ data=somevalue(kp.Value) });
     }
}
```

Async version

```
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TiHub>();

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Sessions, kp =>
            {
                var client = context.Clients.Client(kp.Key);
                if (client != null)
                {
                    client.changed(new Data{ data=somevalue(kp.Value) });
                }
            });

        });
```

I would like a task or async version of "changed". Something like:

```
client.changedAsync(new Data{ data=somevalue(kp.Value) });
```

Is this supported in SignalR ?

Answer (score 0):

Is `client.changed` I/O bound or CPU bound?

I suppose it's I/O bound and you'll benefit from `async-await`.

Instead of the `Parallel.ForEach` you might try something like this:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TiHub>();
var tasks = (from kp in Sessions
             let client = context.Clients.Client(kp.Key)
             where client != null
             select Task.Run(() =>
                 {
                     client.changed(new Data{ data = somevaluekp.Value);
                 })).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But you should try to use natural `async-await` APIs instead of the artificial  Task.Run`.

Comment: SignalR hub does not seem to provide task based methods. ie: it would be nice to have client.changedAsync. I don't want a blocking call here, so i will not await. Thus the reason for creating a thread using Task.Run. Do you know signalr ?

Comment: I know what SignalR is but never used it. I don't understand your comment "I don't want a blocking call here, so i will not await. Thus the reason for creating a thread using Task.Run.".

Comment: well you don't know signalr then, and this is why you are asking this question :)